# Using a Prefix on Non-Public Fields

Tags: c#, coding-style

I don't know anyone who uses a 'm_' to prefix non-public fields (myself included), but I am aware of three reasons why it *should* be done:

1. The CLR specification insists that property names and corresponding fields not differ merely by letter casing.  Some languages are case-insensitive.  “`_`” could be used, but “`m_`” is preferred because names should start with alphabetic characters. (This comes from [coding standards](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2006/08/16/c-coding-standards/) suggested by Dan Rigsby)
2. A mere “`_`” prefix is not CLI compliant, whereas “`m_`” is CLI compliant.
3. Intellisense, at least in WPF as of VS 2008, does not distinguish between types defined in XAML and types defined in code-behind.  A 'm_' used in the code behind would resolve the issue.

My question is this: would you (yes, you!) be able to accept this as a new standard on projects you are currently working on, given the reasons stated, or would you still just lose your mind in unbridled hatred of the idea?

p.s. Please don't tell me "Hungarian" is bad, since this suggestion - in isolation - really has no connection with Hungarian.

Comment: If you are trying to achieve agreement within a team then use the .NET Framework Naming Guidelines as in impartial standard.  It forbids using prefixes btw.  If you are trying to convince yourself then use whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

Most people I know (including myself) just use `_` as a prefix for non public fields. It's shorter to type, and it makes the fields appear all together in intellisense. I also find it more readable than `m_`

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked on SO many times, but once again, it comes down to personal preference and, as long as you are consistent, you're not going to have any problems with either approach.

As far as I know, most C# coding standards call for lower case member variable names with no prefix.  Personally, I don't like this approach because your member variables tend to clash with method parameters, so you constantly have to qualify them with 'this'.

I use a single underscore before the name of member variables, but I am sure there are many people out there who don't like that either.  It boils down to being consistent throughout the code base.

Comment: Is there something that makes `m_` preferable to `this.`, aside from three characters?

Comment: Those three characters do it for me :D.  I like m_ or just _ because it makes it various obvious that we are dealing with a private member variable and it also lines things up in intellisense.  Again, it comes down to personal preference.

Comment: @Ed: Good enough for me; I was genuinely asking if there was something other than the three characters.

Comment: @Ed: Right; your point about having things grouped in Intellisense is along the lines of what I was asking :)

Comment: @Adam: This is probably going to sound like a stretch, but I dislike using `this` just because I view it as similar to a comment in the sense that you could just remove it and the code would behave identically but be less clear. That is, it is syntactically completely optional. Whereas if you actually *name* your variable with a prefix, you *must* refer to it that way, and to leave the prefix out would be an error.

Comment: @Dan: I can go with that; I just generally find that I end up referring to member variables more often *outside* of a scenario where the names conflict. Given that, I generally find it more helpful to have variables that are more closely named to their purpose than it would be to be able to leave `this.` off. But, as always, this is completely personal preference.

Comment: I dislike the use of 'this' because it is redundant, takes more time to type, and makes my code more verbose than it needs to be.  Just useless in most scenarios really.

Comment: just to add to it, the problem with 'this' is it's something that a lot of programmers won't always use. "I don't have a parameter called that so I won't bother adding 'this', while if your members are prefixed with m_ you can look at it and always know the scope.

Answer (score 0):

The *CLS* not *CLR* specification insists that *public and protected* members not differ only by case. It's important to be aware of the fact that there is no need to make your types CLS-compliant unless you plan on using them in other projects that span multiple languages. Even then, if this is an internal project there may not be a need to follow *all* of the CLS guidelines.

In any case, this applies only to members that are potentially visible outside of the declaring assembly (in other words, `private` and `internal` members are exempt), this suggestion is not relevant to non-public fields.

That being said, the concept of naming conventions has been debated since we were able to name variables. Personally, no, I do not like the idea of prefixing variables with `m_`, but that's a personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  It is important that all programmers accept the standards of the projects they are working on - it is a good sign that management is insisting on standards, whether the individual agrees with them or not.

Personally, I think prefixing with "m_" is a waste of a keystroke, but if it's in the standards then that's what I'll adhere to.

If *I* was writing the standards, I would specify that "_" should be used as a prefix to non-public fields.